# How to show tooltip on dhtmlx Gantt Chart above the date row

Tags: javascript, dhtmlx

I have a gantt chart, I have an extra row above date row. Here the text on this row are coming from switch statement by comparing the dates of items of obj variable. Now I just wanted to hover on any cell of top row, for example if I hover on 'one' in tooltip it should show one, if I hover on 'two',it should show two. Below is the code.

### HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='http://cdn.dhtmlx.com/gantt/edge/dhtmlxgantt.css'>
  <script src='http://cdn.dhtmlx.com/gantt/edge/dhtmlxgantt.js'></script>
  <style>
    .gantt_custom_button {
      background-color: rgb(206, 206, 206);
      position: absolute;
      right: -10px;
      top: 5px;
      width: 20px;
      height: 26px;
      border-radius: 0;
    }
  </style>


</head>
<div id='gantt_here' style='width:100%; height:500px;'></div>

<body>
  <script>
    var task1 = {
      'data': [{
          'id': 1,
          'text': 'Project #1',
          'start_date': '01-04-2019',
          'duration': 2,
          'order': 10,
          'progress': 0.4,
          'open': true
        },
        {
          'id': 2,
          'text': 'Task #1',
          'start_date': '02-04-2019',
          'duration': 1,
          'order': 10,
          'progress': 0.6,
          'parent': 1
        },
        {
          'id': 3,
          'text': 'Task #2',
          'start_date': '03-04-2019',
          'duration': 2,
          'order': 20,
          'progress': 0.6,
          'parent': 1
        },
        {
          'id': 4,
          'text': 'Task #3',
          'start_date': '05-04-2019',
          'duration': 1,
          'order': 10,
          'progress': 0.6,
          'parent': 1
        }

      ],
      'links': [{
          'id': 1,
          'source': 1,
          'target': 2,
          'type': '1'
        },
        {
          'id': 2,
          'source': 2,
          'target': 3,
          'type': '0'
        },
        {
          'id': 3,
          'source': 3,
          'target': 4,
          'type': '0'
        },
        {
          'id': 4,
          'source': 2,
          'target': 5,
          'type': '2'
        }
      ]
    };
    const CellDisplay = item => {
      switch (item) {
        case 'item1':
          return 'one';
        case 'item2':
          return 'two';
        case 'item3':
          return 'three';
        case 'item4':
          return 'four';
        case 'item5':
          return 'five';
          case 'item6':
          return 'six';
          case 'item7':
          return 'seven';
      }
    };
    //const nonMilestone = ['']
    const forLaunch = lData => {
      const scale = {
        unit: 'day',
        step: 1,
        format: date => {
          for (const key in lData) {
           console.log(key);
            if(lData.hasOwnProperty(key)){         
            if(lData[key] && date.toISOString().substring(0,10) === lData[key].substring(0,10)){
            //console.log(date.toISOString()+"---"+lData[key].substring(0,10));
            return CellDisplay(key)
            }           
            }            
          }
          return '';
        }

      }
      return scale;
    };
    gantt.config['scales'] = [{
      unit: 'day',
      step: 1,
      format: '%d %M'
    }];
    const Obj = [{
      Id: 575,
      items: {
        item1: '2019-03-30T10:00:00.000+0000',
        item2: '2019-03-31T00:00:00.000+0000',
        item3: '2019-04-01T10:00:00.000+0000',
        item4: '2019-04-02T10:00:00.000+0000',
        item5: '2019-04-03T10:00:00.000+0000',
        item6: '2019-04-04T10:00:00.000+0000',
        item7: '2019-04-05T10:00:00.000+0000'
      },
      active: false
    }];
    Obj.forEach(data => {
      gantt.config['scales'].unshift(forLaunch(data.items));
    });
    gantt.init('gantt_here');
    gantt.parse(task1);
  </script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to manually attach the tooltip to the scale cells and return their innerHTML:

```
gantt.ext.tooltips.tooltipFor({
  selector: ".gantt_scale_cell",
  html: function(event, domElement){
    return domElement.innerHTML;
  }
});
```

https://docs.dhtmlx.com/gantt/desktop__tooltips.html#tooltipsfordifferentelements

Here is an example:

http://snippet.dhtmlx.com/5/74db67ba5